# How can I get multiple (UDP) clients to only receive packets from a specific server?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, client-server, client

I'm creating an interface where multiple clients send periodic updates to a server (which stores all their addresses), and then the server sends packets that include all of the client updates to all the clients. It looks like it all should work right, but when I run the server and client together, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:95)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:376)
at cygnus.client.CygnusClient.main(CygnusClient.java:51)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

The lines it speaks of are (in the client):

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("server.ip.address", 7777);
socket.bind(address);
```

The server opens the socket like this:

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(9999);
```

Note: I am running the server on the same network as the client, which is where I'm guessing the error is coming from. Unfortunately, I would like to be able to run the server and client on the same computer (and have other clients on other computers), especially for testing purposes.

How can I make sure the client only listens to packets from my server at its port? Is there a better way to do this?

P.S. Let me know if I need to include any more of the code to help answer this question, I would be happy to, I just don't know what I need to include.

Comment: Are you also binding your clients to some port?

Comment: The code above is from the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UDP client is not suppose to listen on a port. It just sends a DatagramPacket to UDP server and receives the response. The port to be used for client socket is managed by os.

```
// any free port will be assigned by os
DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(); 
// create a packet to be sent ot server
DatagramPacket requestPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, outBuf.length, serverAddress, 9999);
// sending the packet to udp server 
clientSocket.send(requestPacket); 

DatagramPacket responsePacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length)
// client will be blocked until a response is sent by server
clientSocket.receive(responsePacket);
```

On server side

```
 DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(9999); 
 DatagramPacket requestPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length);
 // will be blocked until a request is received by the server
 socket.receive(requestPacket); 
 // the client's port and ip address will be populated in the packet on receiving a request.
 DatagramPacket responsePacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, outBuf.length, requestPacket.getAddress(), requestPacket.getPort());
 // the data will be sent to the client.
 socket.send(responsePacket);
```

Comment: You don't even need to create a new packet for the reply. Just reuse the one the request came in, calling `setData()` with the reply data, and leaving the source-address and -port undisturbed.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure the client only listens to packets from my server at its port?

Just `connect()` the client sockets to that IP:port. Then they won't receive from anyone else.